# Error in config Bitbucket to StackStorm in Linux 18.04

Tags: linux

I'm trying to integrate Bitbucket in my StackStorm and everytime I try:

```
st2 run bitbucket.[anything]
```

I get the error:

```
status: failed
parameters: None
result: 
  exit_code: 1
  result: None
  stderr: "  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 183
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
"
  stdout: ''
```

Anyone have any idea?